# MPD Hangs when trying to use JACK

Tags: audio

I'm trying to get MPD working with JACK, and I'm running into a problem. When I don't specify an output in mpd.conf:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo mpd -v --no-daemon                                                                                                                           
config_file: loading file /etc/mpd.conf
Sep 05 02:12 : path: SetFSCharset: fs charset is: UTF-8
Sep 05 02:12 : libsamplerate: libsamplerate converter 'Fastest Sinc Interpolator'
Sep 05 02:12 : vorbis: Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.4
Sep 05 02:12 : opus: libopus 1.1
Sep 05 02:12 : sndfile: libsndfile-1.0.25
Sep 05 02:12 : adplug: adplug 2.2.1
Sep 05 02:12 : db: reading DB
Sep 05 02:12 : output: No 'AudioOutput' defined in config file
Sep 05 02:12 : output: Attempt to detect audio output device
Sep 05 02:12 : output: Attempting to detect a alsa audio device
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Sep 05 02:12 : output: Successfully detected a alsa audio device
Sep 05 02:12 : curl: version 7.38.0
Sep 05 02:12 : curl: with GnuTLS/3.3.8
```

And it starts working. But when I specify a JACK output as follows:

```
audio_output {
        type            "jack"
        device          "hw:1,0"
        autostart       "yes"
}
```

I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo mpd -v --no-daemon
config_file: loading file /etc/mpd.conf
Sep 05 02:21 : path: SetFSCharset: fs charset is: UTF-8
Sep 05 02:21 : libsamplerate: libsamplerate converter 'Fastest Sinc Interpolator'
Sep 05 02:21 : vorbis: Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.4
Sep 05 02:21 : opus: libopus 1.1
Sep 05 02:21 : sndfile: libsndfile-1.0.25
Sep 05 02:21 : adplug: adplug 2.2.1
Sep 05 02:21 : db: reading DB
```

And nothing can connect. It binds to 6600 and will establish TCP connections but nothing happens (i.e. mpc times out). Unlike [MPD hangs on song change](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54411/mpd-hangs-on-song-change), this is killable with CTRL+C or just a standard SIGINT. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems to debug:

1 Make sure `jackd` is running. Don't try MPD to start it yet. You refer to an alsa device `hw:1,0` which is non-default, that is a USB sound card, or possibly an audio HAT. This reference is buggy by itself, as it belongs to the alsa output plugin. 
`jackd` should start fine nowadays as long as you are logged in a graphical session. (`jackd2` is the default on Raspbian, and relies upon a working DBUS session IIRC)
Try `/usr/bin/jackd` on the command line and edit your post with the output you get.

2 Make sure MPD connects to your jack output ports.

`audio_output {
        type            "jack"
        destination_ports  "system:playback_1,system:playback_2"
}`

See https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/output_plugins.html for details.

Comment: Jack starts and runs fine. I've already made sure of this. I'll try using the destination ports and see if if works.